# Dynamic content providing endpoint as audio source, either skipping not working or download not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, audio, range

## What I have

I have a page which returns a music file based on a unique id.

e.g.

```
Source.aspx?id=15 // returns 01_myfile.mp3
Source.aspx?id=37 // returns 02_something.flac
Source.aspx?id=3 // returns 03_anotherone.ogg
```

i want to use these sources in a `html5 <audio> tag`. I got it to working at some point but I wasn't able to skip within the file. That was when I foudn out about the `Range` header and tried implementing this.

```
...
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.StatusCode = (Int32) HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename=\"{file.FullName}\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString()); // e.g. 100
Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", $"{rangeFrom}-{rangeTo - 1}/{fileLength}"); // e.g. 0-99/100
Response.ContentType = GetContentType(file); // e.g. "audio/mpeg"
String contentDuration = t.Duration?.ToString() ?? "360"; // duration of the audio file or some default guess
Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Duration", contentDuration);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Duration", contentDuration);
Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName, rangeFrom, rangeTo - rangeFrom); // transmit requested section
Response.End();
```

## How it looks

Request (Chrome)
[image: Request on chrome browser]

```
Request URL:...Source.aspx?id=17686
Request Method:GET
Status Code:206 Partial Content
Remote Address:[::1]:51000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="Z:\music\...\mymusicfile.mp3"
Content-Duration:360
Content-Length:12683228
Content-Range:0-12683227/12683228
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Date:Tue, 12 Dec 2017 15:33:23 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Content-Duration:360
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?...?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:.ASPXAUTH=...
Host:localhost:51000
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
id:17686
```

It just deactivates the control.
[image: activated and deactivated controls]

## Problem

So. What am I missing? Why does this version not provide the file as expected?

Download doesn't work either.
[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that `Content-Range` needs a unit. e. g. `bytes`. But I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like i figured in my comment, i was missing the unit in the `Content-Range`. By fixing this the skipping and seeking within an audio file works like a charm.

## Content Range Unit

Change the `Content-Range` format from...

```
0-99/100
```

... to ...

```
bytes 0-99/100
```

Notice the `bytes` part? That's the unit.

## Status Code

Responding with the correct status code is crucial for all features to work properly.

The range header is not always included. Depending on this you have to respond with a different HTTP status code.

> - **1st case:**  If a *range header with wrong format* is provided, respond with a `416` *Requested-Range-Not-Satisfiable* HTTP status code, no meta data headers like Content-Range and no file attached
> - **2nd case:**  If *no range header* is provided, respond with a `200` *OK* HTTP status code, all meta data headers listed in the OP and the full file content range attached
> - **3rd case:**  If a *`0-` range header* is provided, also respond with a `200` *OK* HTTP status code and the full file content range attached
> - **4th case:**  For *any another range header* provided, respond with a `206` *Partial Content* HTTP status code  and the requested content range

---

## Full working code for dynamic content providing endpoint

```
private readonly Dictionary<String, String> _mimeTypes =
    new Dictionary<String, String> {{".mp3", "audio/mpeg"}, {".wav", "audio/vnd.wav"}}; // all audio mime types i am interessted in which do not follow the "audio/fileextension" format
            
private void DownloadFile(String path)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

    Int64 fileLength = file.Length;
    Int64 rangeTo = fileLength;
    String rangeHeader = Request.Headers["range"];
    String[] parts;

    if (rangeHeader != null)
    {
        rangeHeader = rangeHeader.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Trim().Replace("bytes=", ""); // comes with the format of "bytes=0-100"
        parts = rangeHeader.Split('-').Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray(); splits into "0" and "100"
    }
    else
    {
        parts = new[] {"0"}; // simulate 0- range, full file will be returned
    }

    // trying to parse range
    Int64 rangeFrom = 0;
    switch (parts.Length)
    {
        case 2:
        {
            // full range passed (e.g. "100-200")
            if (!Int64.TryParse(parts[1], out rangeTo))
            {
                // cannot parse input to int -> invalid
                SendResponseRangeNotSatisfiable();
                return;
            }

            goto case 1;
        }
        case 1:
            // only start provided (e.g. "0-")
            if (!Int64.TryParse(parts[0], out rangeFrom))
            {
                // cannot parse input to int -> invalid
                SendResponseRangeNotSatisfiable();
                return;
            }

            goto case 0;
        case 0:
        {
            // no range provided, take default value for full file (e.g. "0-..")
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.StatusCode = rangeFrom == 0 && rangeTo == fileLength
                ? (Int32) HttpStatusCode.OK
                : (Int32) HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
            Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename=\"{file.FullName}\"");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", $"bytes {rangeFrom}-{rangeTo - 1}/{fileLength}");
            Response.ContentType = _mimeTypes.ContainsKey(file.Extension)
                ? _mimeTypes[file.Extension]
                : $"audio/{file.Extension.Substring(1)}";
            String contentDuration = TheLengthOfYourMusicFileInSeconds;
            Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Duration", contentDuration);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Duration", contentDuration);
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName, rangeFrom, rangeTo - rangeFrom);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            break;
        }
        default:
            SendResponseRangeNotSatisfiable();
            return;
    }
}

private void SendResponseRangeNotSatisfiable()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.StatusCode = (Int32) HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```